# .NET Core 6.0 standalone binary compilation

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm trying to create a .NET Core 6.0 binary as a standalone, with all dependencies packaged in one `.exe` file.

The trouble I am having is that whilst the binary compiles ok it is reliant on the DLLs placed in the Release/Debug folder.

I have tried compiling from the command line with

```
dotnet publish --standalone
```

but in that instance I just get a similar issue with a load more DLLs and the binary itself is the same size and needs to be in that folder to run.

Is what I'm looking for even possible and if so how can this be achieved? I have tried with Visual Studio, `dotnet` cli and Rider so far.

There are a number of old solutions that mention solutions such as `ilmerge` but this appears to have been long since deprecated and is no longer maintained.

-- EDIT for future me:

Final solution looked like this, thanks to Andrew's answer below.

My final project.csproj file looked like this based on [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file#publish-a-single-file-app---visual-studio)

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
    <EnableCompressionInSingleFile>true</EnableCompressionInSingleFile>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <PublishReadyToRun>true</PublishReadyToRun>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Publish either via Visual Studio GUI or:

```
dotnet publish -c release -r win-x64
```

Comment: standalone means the package will include all dependencies. Packaging these in a single exe is would be [Single File deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file). Both options should be possible to combine.

Comment: Could you add a minimal .csproj file showing what you are currently trying?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest looking at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file which should hopefully be up to date.  I believe the key bit is `<PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>` in the .csproj.